# Process.MainModule Access Is Denied

Tags: c#, memory, process, system.diagnostics

I'm using the System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessByName() to get access to a wcf service host that runs as a windows service.

The process hosts multiple services and I'm trying to access the WorkingSet64 for one of the services. When i call System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessByName()  4 processes are returned for the name provided, when i loop through these processes and access the Process.MainModule.Filename i get an "Access Denied" error.

The process runs as a system process, when i run the code on my dev machine it seems to return the information i am expecting (ACL is turned off) when i run the code on the server (ACL turned on) an access is denied exception is thrown.

I've seen this issue mentioned in a few places but most of the answers suggest to just skip the inaccessible items with a try catch and that isn't what i want, i need to inspect the inaccessible items.

Code below demonstrates an example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Process[] service;
        service = Process.GetProcesses();

        Console.WriteLine(service.Count());

        foreach (var s in service)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s.ProcessName);

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s.WorkingSet64);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR---"  + ex.Message);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("-------------------");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You are setting yourself up for guaranteed failure as long as you iterate GetProcesses().  You have to be selective to avoid the ones you can never get access to.  The point of using WCF is to never have to do this.

Comment: I'm unsure why this is being flagged for close, it's clear what is being asked and it's not 'broad'. The user wants to get all processes currently running but the service permissions are not high enough and he gets Access Denied. Without creating a specific Admin User for the service to run under I donno how you would solve this...

Comment: The *only* way to solve it is to run the service with admin rights.  That's the point of access control...

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate the point of access control, I was just wondering if anyone had any intelligent suggestions on how to better implement this so I can access the information I need.

In the end I've implemented an internal windows service that I can call with the name of the service process information I want to access, the trick being this internal service runs with the same access as our other internal processes.

When I call the internal service it has no problems accessing the process information of any of the other windows services.